# Matlab or Octave plot auto-generated dates on x axis

Tags: date, plot, octave

I have a few hundred integer measurements. They are taken daily. I know the first measurement was taken on the 3/3/2019. I do not have any date explicitly related to each measurement.   I would like to plot these values on the y axis and the consecutive dates on the x axis.  I would also like to plot a subset of these measurements.For example, from 6/6/2019 until 11/11/2019, preferably by supplying only the initial start date and the two subset dates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is rather broad I'm afraid, see [ask]. Especially because you are asking about different, not always compatible languages (MATLAB is not Octave), please [edit] the post to include **your own attempt** at solving this (in either of the languages), then [edit] the post to contain that (non-working), code, called a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (I tried it in Octave, but should also work in MATLAB):

```
data = randi(100,50,1); % some random data

start_date = datenum('03/03/2019','dd/mm/yyyy');
dates = start_date + (1:length(data));

% Plot data
figure
plot(dates,data)
datetick('dd/mm')

% Plot subset of the data
dates_start  = datenum('16/03/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'); % change to your actual start date
dates_end = datenum('05/04/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'); % change to your actual end date
dates_subset = dates(dates>=dates_start & dates <=dates_end);
data_subset = data(dates>=dates_start & dates <=dates_end);
figure
plot(dates_subset,data_subset)
datetick('dd/mm')
```

This produces the following plots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of date times and use it as the x-axis. Check out the [Date and Time Arithmetic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compute-elapsed-time.html) in MATLAB.

To create the time-vector, just add a `duration` (in hours) to your initial date

```
% number of samples/data/dates
NumSmpl = 100;
DateVec = datetime(2019,3,3,12,0,0) + duration((1:NumSmpl)*24,0,0).'; % I prefer to have vectors rather than arrays, which is why I transpose it here
```

Now plot your data

```
% assuming this is your signal
Sig = 1:NumSmpl;

subplot(2,2,1:2) % activate first row
plot(DateVec,Sig)

subplot(2,2,3) % bottom left
plot(DateVec,Sig)
% set axes limits
xlim([DateVec(3),DateVec(10)])

subplot(2,2,4) % bottom right
% plot only a fraction of the data
lg = DateVec > datetime(2019,3,6) & DateVec < datetime(2019,3,13);
plot(DateVec(lg),Sig(lg))
```

I used two different ways of showing a portion of the plot. One by using `xlim` and the other by using logical indexing.

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Note that `subplot` is superseded by [`tiledlayout`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) in recent MATLAB versions.

Comment: @Adriaan thx, I was unaware of this command. But there hasn't been a warning from TheMathworks, so I assume that it will remain available for at least two more years =)